# Access older Git commits after accidentially pulling from remote repo with different commit history

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab

I have a local Git repo with existing commits spanning several months. I have created a fresh repo on GitLab, initialized with a README file, so it has one commit.

After adding the origin to my local repo, I pulled, and now I see only that one commit from origin and all the other ones in the history of my local repo are gone.
The `.git` folder is still 6GB though.

What is the right approach to remove the commit that came from origin and get access to my original commits again?

Comment: What does `git reflog` show you?

Comment: What command did you type, which showed you this one commit long history ?

Comment: `git pull` from an empty repository should have no effect at all.  Showing your exact commands here will help others diagnose what really went wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe shows all the commits before the pull, thanks.

Comment: @LeGEC `git log`

Comment: @torek not exactly empty, I initialized the new remote repo with a README, so it had 1 commit. And that's all that was shown on my local repo after pulling.

Comment: OK, yes, that's definitely *not* an empty repository. But the result of `git merge` should have been an error ("refusing to merge unrelated histories") unless your Git is very old. If your Git is old *enough*, perhaps you hit one of those nasty little `git pull` bugs that I hit back in the late 2000s or early 2010s, that is one of the reasons I almost never actually run `git pull` at all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Partial success:

How to get invisible commits back: https://megakemp.com/2017/10/19/the-invisible-commits-part-one/

List all commits: `git reflog`

We see all the commits, and pos 3 would be our local repo before pulling from empty remote repo:

```
9518fc7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
9518fc7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
9518fc7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{2}: pull: checkout 9518fc7b174ce9cfc87124e510128b1b0f8883d8
f468053 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from b894f7ca01f8d1418d9b83bc22e7f728e42e16ba to master
b894f7c HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to b894f7ca01f8d1418d9b83bc22e7f728e42e16ba
f468053 HEAD@{5}: rebase: updating HEAD
f468053 HEAD@{6}: rebase: aborting
bd4c2c6 HEAD@{7}: rebase: checkout origin/master
f468053 HEAD@{8}: rebase: updating HEAD
f468053 HEAD@{9}: rebase: aborting
bd4c2c6 HEAD@{10}: rebase: checkout origin/master
f468053 HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from f468053e2a1c646b0406868b900c180d974b1bc7 to master
f468053 HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from bd4c2c6c5e7b5e9fc385f582df3bf0bd2028de11 to f468053e2a1c646b0406868b900c180d974b1bc7
bd4c2c6 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from master to bd4c2c6c5e7b5e9fc385f582df3bf0bd2028de11
f468053 HEAD@{14}: commit (amend): - release 0.8.33
bd4c2c6 HEAD@{15}: commit: - release 0.8.33
```

This failed: `git reset --hard master~3 --` 
With error: `fatal: Failed to resolve 'master~3' as a valid revision.`

This worked: `git reset --hard @{3}`

Well kinda. It got the old history back, but doesn't end up at the commit that should be pos 3 according to the list above. But at least I can see all my commits again.